# LangChain/OpenAI error: "openai.ChatCompletion but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0", but I am not using openai.ChatCompletion

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

My code was running fine about a month or two ago, but it seems that there has been an update to OpenAI.

I keep getting the error below, however, as you can see in the code I did not use `openai.ChatCompletion`, so I am not sure why am I getting this error and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

The purpose of this code is to take in a prompt template with 2 variables, `question` and `text`, and then the LLM should take in this prompt and give the output answer.

Could someone please help with this?

Thank you in advance.

CODE:

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

llm = OpenAI(model_name=model, openai_api_key=api_key)

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["question","text"],
    template=template,
)

llm(prompt.format(question=var1,text=var2))
```

ERROR:

```
APIRemovedInV1: 

You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface. 

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating chat agent with langchain and openai getting no attribute error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77457590/creating-chat-agent-with-langchain-and-openai-getting-no-attribute-error)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, since I am importing OpenAI from LangChain "pip install langchain openai", and not separately

Comment: openai sdk is updated but langchain has not updated yet. so versions are conflicting. you have to downgrade to `pip install openai==0.27.4`

Answer (score 1):

You import `ChatOpenAI` but don't initilize your model by using it. Instead you should use `llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name=model, openai_api_key=api_key)`. This replacement should solve the problem. Also make sure that you're using both the latest versions of langchain and openai.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your langchain version by:

```
pip install -U langchain
```